# What information do browsers use to create the Accept-Language string?

Tags: google-chrome, http, firefox, locale

I'm trying to get as much regional information as possible about users visiting a website. Mapping the IP to a country using e.g. ipinfo.io is one method, but I'm also exploring the Accept-Language header. Getting this using HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE in PHP. I would like to ask if someone knows how this is actually computed? I understand that it is up to the browser, and the implementation is different depending on browser, but is there some documentation available or interesting article written on this?

I'm using Linux, my operation system language is English, and I have a Swedish keyboard layout. For Chrome I see this string:

```
en-US,en;q=0.8,nl;q=0.6,sv;q=0.4
```

Which indicates that I'm interested in English and Swedish, which makes sense, but then there is also Dutch there, where might this have come from?

For Firefox I only see:

```
en-US,en;q=0.5
```

Anyone who has done some more research on this? Any other tips or comments regarding how to get regional information about visitors of websites?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will likely depend on both browser and platform. On unix type operating systems you can find the system locale with the `locale` command:

```
$ locale
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

You can also set this using the same command, or via the OSX system preferences app. Browser's will likely default to the system locale, but most of them will also offer a way for the user to change their preferences within the browser. See http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-lang-priorities.en.php for a good overview.

Here's some of the chrome code that looks to be related to setting the actual accept-language header: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/ui/base/l10n/l10n_util.cc&q=AcceptLanguage&sq=package:chromium&type=cs&l=856

Here's a firefox bug report related to the accept-language header that contains a lot of interesting discussion and links to diffs that relate to setting the header: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1054739

Here's a mozilla developer article that gives some details about the accept-language header, and some related ones: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Content_negotiation

Ultimately, the accept-language is controllable by the user (and there are lots of browser extensions to quickly modify it), so while it's useful to detect the user's language preference it doesn't necessarily tell you anything about their location. You could combine it with other information such as the user's timezone (available from javascript), but if you really want location information then something like http://ipinfo.io is your best bet.